# How do I create a database pipeline to create/update/merge/delete pandas/csv/sql data in a central database?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have 1300 csv files in a directory in a google cloud storage bucket.

Each file has a date in the first column, followed by daily data for the last 20-30 years which spans another 8 columns.

So like this,
Data1.csv

```
Date source1 source2 source3 source4 source5 source6 source7 source8
```

I have 30 separate servers which asynchronously update the Data. Server1 will handle Data1-Data40, Server2 will handle Data41-Data80.. etc. When a server gets an update in data, I store them to a bucket using the following command.

```
import pandas as pd

def some_update_function(DataNumber):
    #somefunction
    return dataframe

listofDataNumbers = ['Data1','Data2','Data3',....,'Data40']
for i in listofDataNumbers:
    df = some_update_function(i)
    df.to_csv('gs://storage-instance/files/'+'i')
```

Currently, I am storing them in a google cloud storage bucket. I am doing this so that I have a central location where I can access the files. However, when I want to merge them, I first have to download them 1 by 1, then run the merge command like this.

First i use this terminal command to download the files one by one.

```
gsutil cp -r gs://storage-instance/files /Users/user/Documents/files
```

Then I merge the files into a one big dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd 
frame = []

for filename in os.listdir(filepath): #filepath has the rest of the files
    file_path = os.path.join(filepath, filename)
    df = (pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=0)
          .groupby(['Date']).first()
          .add_prefix(f"{filename}-"))
    frame.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(frame, axis=1, join='outer')
```

I am merging these files column wise.

Now I have dataframe which is `1+(1300x8)` by `number of dates for 30 years` which I can run data analysis on.

Right now the merge of the frames only takes around 2 minutes, however, the download takes 20 minutes.

Is there a better way for me to store this data and access it faster?

I want to be able to:

1. continue updating my 1300 dataframes on a daily basis they could each take up a table in a database or a column in a database, but I must be able to easily access and update them
2. Access the database quickly to quickly to create a big dataframe like i did above.
3. It must take less than the current 22 minutes in total it takes to download and merge the frames.

I tried to create a postgresql database and upload files using sqlalchemy in python.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import psycopg2

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://user@127.0.0.1',isolation_level='AUTOCOMMIT')

engine.execute('CREATE DATABASE Data1')

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/user/Documents/files/Data1.csv",index_col=0)
df.to_sql('Data1',con=engine,if_exists='replace')
```

But I can't figure out how to concat all the tables together at once, I can only seem to store table by table. Can someone help me figure a better way to do this? I have no idea where to start.

Comment: there's more than 8 columns. there's (1300x8)+1, the 1 being the Date column. However, I need to be able to centrally store/update/delete/add this, any ideas ?

Comment: so just 1 database would be best with 3 columns right?

Comment: the data comes to me in the form of csv data so I thought pandas would be the best

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223331/discussion-between-anarchy-and-parfait).

Comment: I tried to do 3 columns in SQL, its taking forever